# Sort numbers into Array by xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, xcode, sorting

i have a problem when i try to sort an array by one table.

I want to get this:

1
 2
 3
 25

and **now the result of the sort** array is this:

1
 2
 25
 3

Now i´m trying with this code:

_ItemsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[Tools getSortedArray:tempDatesArr sortBy:@"likes" ascending:NO]];

What i could to do?

Thank you!

Comment: Show us the method that sorts the array. Also are you numbers real numbers (instances of NSNumber) or strings ?

Comment: are you by any chance sorting strings and not actual numbers?

Comment: Are String format. This is the method:   +(NSArray *)getSortedArrayFromSourceArray:(NSArray *)sourceArray sortBy:(NSString *)key ascending:(BOOL)ascending;

Comment: I meant the code of this method..

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a separated method to sort those numbers. `NSMutableArray` can do that just fine.

If your array contains `NSNumber`, you can sort it by:

```
[array sortUsingDescriptors:@[ [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:Nil ascending:NO] ]];
```

If your array contains number **as `NSString`**:

```
// Use intValue or whatever key match your number type
[array sortUsingDescriptors:@[ [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"intValue" ascending:NO] ]];
```

Comment: I have tried this :_ItemsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] sortUsingDescriptors:@[ [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"likes" ascending:NO] ]];   but i get this problem: NSMutableArray  *__strong from incompatible type 'void'

Comment: `sortUsingDescriptor:` does not return a `NSMutableArray`. It sorts the caller array. So you can't use it like `[[NSMutableArray alloc] sort...]`. If your array is `_ItemsArray`, you need to call `[_ItemsArray sortUsingDescriptors...]` and it will apply the result to your array.